# How to Vagrant scotchbox subdomain virtualhost

Tags: vagrant, apache2, localhost, subdomain, virtual-hosts

I have installed vagrant and scotchbox from scotch.io to develop locally and is running like a charm.
Now I need use the subdomains as variable, and i have googled  about, but still no working.
I have changed the hosts file and added

```
192.168.33.10  scotch.box
```

Is needed add a line for wildcard subdomain hosts?
Also I have added the next line to my conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public
    ServerName tenant.scotch.box
    ServerAlias *.scotch.box
</VirtualHost>
```

Sorry for my broken english.

Answer (score 1):

Just add 
192.168.33.10  tenant.scotch.box
to hosts.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a couple of months ago. On the hosting OS you have to edit the hosts file. 
On Windows

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

On linux

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

you have then to add the ip-address of your scotch box with the desired host name

```
192.168.33.10 tenant.scotch.box
```

You can even add multiple lines to your hosts file if you have multiple subdomains or you are developing multiple web applications on the same scotch box. For example :

```
192.168.33.10 sub1.scotch.box
192.168.33.10 sub2.scotch.box
192.168.33.10 sub3.scotch.box
```

BUT don't forget to edit the virtual host file inside Scotch Box which is located `/etc/apache2/sites-available/YOUR_CONFIG.conf`

You will need a `<VirtualHost *:80> </VirtualHost>` for each sub domain. Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/public
  ServerName sub1.scotch.box
  ServerAlias *.scotch.box
</VirtualHost>
```